# Compare time with time zone (Z at the end) with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601, rfc3339

I am trying to compare two dates - today and date from db.
Db date format is `2021-10-04T21:00:00Z` and today date is `2023-08-11 09:06:10` (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`).

How to compare these dates?

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime, gmtime

today_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

due_date = datetime.strptime(date_from_db, date_format)
if due_date < today_time:
    # ...
```

And I get following exception:

```
ValueError: time data '2021-10-04T21:00:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: to parse an ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 datetime string like "2021-10-04T21:00:00Z", use directive "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z" or [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) in Python 3.11+

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066805/python-how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-without-knowing-the-format